# Getting an XML API response in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to ports some code over from Groovy to Java and I'm having trouble capturing the actual XML API response and hoping someone can help me. Here's the relevant code. The API executes successfully but the last two lines aren't working of course.

```
 // open our connection and set some properties
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
 connection.setDoOutput(true);
 connection.setDoInput(true);

 //execute the API
 DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
 wr.writeBytes(xmlString);
 wr.flush();
 wr.close();

 System.out.println("Executing search from " + origin + " to " + destination  + " from " + departureDate + " to " + returnDate);
 // now get the response
 System.out.println("Response Message: " + connection.getResponseMessage() + ", Code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
 Stream<String> xmlResponse = (bufferedReader).lines(); // need to fix this if possible
 // DEBUG ONLY:
 System.out.println("Response: " + xmlResponse);
```

Comment: Can you please post the output?

Comment: Executing search from BOS to LAX from 2018-02-01T10:12:49 to 2018-02-01T10:12:49
     Response Message: OK, Code: 200
     Response: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@404b9385

Comment: The response text should be a full XML reply about 50KB in length.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently printing out the reference to the `xmlResponse` stream rather than the `String` instances inside the stream.

You can do: `xmlResponse.forEach(System.out::println);` to print out each line.

To turn the response into a String you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to run v1.7. How would do that in 1.7?